# Eclipse does not recognize my android device

Tags: android, eclipse

My android device is a cutePad TX-A7108, with Android OS 4.2.2.

I have enabled USB Debugging on it, but when I plug it to my laptop via a USB cable, and then run my Android project on Eclipse, the Device Window doesn't show it on the Device List.

I have a Samsung Galaxy running Android 2.3. When I plug it to my laptop and run the same Android project, it works as it normally should.

I am developing Android apps on Windows 8 OS. My android SDK has been setup with most of the used APIs(10, 16, 18, 19), tools and supported libraries.

Please help me out with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. Right Click on **"My Computer"** choose "**properties**".
2. Go into **Device Manager** there you can find **your device(cutePad)** ***right click*** on that and **choose update device drive let windows search online if windows could find the updates try to locate on your own**

Hope it Helps..!!

Answer (score 0):

you should install device drivers for that tab, then try running project directly from the eclipse.